# How to disable cipher RC4 in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: tls, apache, cipher-selection

I have been doing Network Scan for our box and Ncircle reported [SSL Server support RC4 ciphers for SSLv3](https://purecloud.ncircle.com/aspl/2481774/LAYaejLCi4UnkTEy0wF8tm-ecrQ/). Based on that I did a search and I plan to add to `/etc/apache/conf.d/security` the following:

```
SSLProtocol -ALL +SSLv3 +TLSv1
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:!LOW:!SSLv2:!EXPORT
```

So if I understand well, the sign `!` is a negation like in a programming language then my rules shoul be the following:

```
SSLProtocol -ALL +SSLv3 +TLSv1
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:!LOW:!SSLv2:!EXPORT
```

I kept on reading the report and There were complain about [support for CBC](https://purecloud.ncircle.com/aspl/2481779/u6VJJeUto9ScgAjWgAA4fLVza94/) and [weak MAC](https://purecloud.ncircle.com/aspl/2480945/tNVk7-rGkq2243_5BU_NNFqGFg8/)

I searched on and I found 2 blogs [hynek.me](https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/) and [raymii.org](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Strong_SSL_Security_On_Apache2.html). I am a little bit confuse. Which directive are recent address my current issues.

A little enlightenment is needed for me to pluck this. Thank you

**EDIT:**

After much trouble and reading. I have come up with this:

```
ALL:!ADH:!RC4:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:!LOW:!SSLv2:!SSLv3!EXPORT
```

I have checked with

```
openssl ciphers -V 'ALL:!ADH:!RC4:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:!LOW:!SSLv2:!SSLv3!EXPORT' | grep CBC

openssl ciphers -V 'ALL:!ADH:!RC4:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:!LOW:!SSLv2:!SSLv3!EXPORT' | grep RC4
```

I am not sure whether this is good enough. I suspect some browsers might have compatibility issues with that.

Answer (score 7):

There are still some RC4 ciphers in your list. To check which ciphers are offered by the server enter your list into 'openssl ciphers -V', i.e.

```
  $ openssl ciphers -V 'ALL:!ADH:!RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:!LOW:!SSLv2:!EXPORT' | grep RC4
      0xC0,0x11 - ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA       SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=SHA1
      0xC0,0x07 - ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=SHA1
      0xC0,0x16 - AECDH-RC4-SHA           SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=None Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=SHA1
      0xC0,0x0C - ECDH-RSA-RC4-SHA        SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=SHA1
      0xC0,0x02 - ECDH-ECDSA-RC4-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=SHA1
      0x00,0x8A - PSK-RC4-SHA             SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=SHA1
```

A good source for how to configure your server correctly is ssllabs.com. For examples of useful cipher settings see https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2013/08/05/configuring-apache-nginx-and-openssl-for-forward-secrecy.

Comment: Hello Thanks for your suggestion. the requirement of the post on Qualys is apache 2.4 . I am running apache 2.2.22(ubuntu 12.04). Commands on Qualys and hynek.me are similar so I used the capital v switch like in your command: openssl ciphers -V 'ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS' | grep RC4

Comment: How to I check disabling of CBC?

Comment: replace the `grep RC4` with `grep CBC`

Comment: I have made some updates. But doubting whether that is fine

Comment: Check you site against https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html. It will tell you if common browsers will have problems with the ciphers. Since you neither have 3DES nor RC4 I'm sure that IE8 will not work.